# Comment formatting in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, word-wrap

Under Options>Editor>Formatting>Java>Comments I have "Wrap Text At Right Margin" enabled, but my comments continue past the red line and don't wrap until they reach the edge of my window. How do I get my comments (and lines of code for that matter) to wrap at the right margin shown by the red line?

Comment: I've reproduced the same behavior in Netbeans 8.1, with default settings. Maybe a Netbeans bug?

Answer (score 1):

This setting only applies to Javadoc. Plus you will have to reformat the source (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). Comments in code and code itself are not affected.